# Unable to start Mysql Sever: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2): Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, localhost

I'm trying to run the Mysql service on my Ubuntu 20.04.

```
mysql
```

gives me error

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

When I run

```
systemctl status mysql.service
```

It's giving me an error

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-01-23 13:01:11 IST; 1min 5s ago
    Process: 59163 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 23 13:01:11 cisco systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jan 23 13:01:11 cisco systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jan 23 13:01:11 cisco systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jan 23 13:01:11 cisco systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 23 13:01:11 cisco systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.

journalctl -xe
```

Output

```
Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 13755 and the job result is failed.
Jan 23 13:02:50 cisco systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Jan 23 13:02:50 cisco systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 13822 and the job result is done.
Jan 23 13:02:50 cisco systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jan 23 13:02:50 cisco systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 23 13:02:50 cisco systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 13822 and the job result is failed.
```

So I purge the MySQL and re-install it using:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql\*
sudo apt autoclean
```

But when I'm re-installing

```
sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client
It's giving me errors.
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.postinst: line 191: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Setting up mysql-client (8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubun
tu3.15) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I re-configure dpkg with

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
But it's giving me an error
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.postinst: line 191: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
```

So in an attempt to fix it I run the command

```
sudo apt install --fix-broken
```

But it's also giving me the same error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.postinst: line 191: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So kindly help me out on how to fix this issue.